# Problem extending BookNavigationBlock

Tags: blocks, plugins, 8

i have a Problem extending a BookNavigationBlock Plugin. When I extend BlockBase it works, but when trying to extend BookNavigationBlock, it fails when placing the block, without any error messages. What am I missing here? (The Code is inside modules/ifg_book_navigation/src/Plugin/Block/IfgBookNavigationBlock.php)

```
namespace Drupal\ifg_book_navigation\Plugin\Block;

use Drupal\book\Plugin\Block;
/**
 * Provides a fully expanded 'Book navigation' block.
 *
 * @Block(
 *   id = "ifg_book_navigation",
 *   admin_label = @Translation("Expanded Book navigation"),
 *   category = @Translation("Menus")
 * )
 */
class IfgBookNavigationBlock extends BookNavigationBlock {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function build() {
    return array(
      '#markup' => $this->t('Hello, World!'),
    );
  }
}
```

Thanx!

UPDATE:
I could trace the Problem to the Plugin Factory.
In the getPluginClass method of DefaultFactory it is checked if the class exists:

```
if (!class_exists($class)) {
  throw new PluginException(sprintf('Plugin (%s) instance class "%s" does not exist.', $plugin_id, $class));
}
```

The value of $class is Drupal\ifg_book_navigation\Plugin\Block\IfgBookNavigationBlock which seems to be correct. However class_exists() itself seems to fail, not even returning false. This could have something to do with autoloading, as by default class_exists() tries this by default ...

UPDATE: It seems like the behaviour is the same for other existing blocks, just tested UserLoginBlock

Comment: _it fails when trying to Place the blog_ I suppose you meant block?

Comment: exactly – edited

Comment: For what it's worth I have encountered exactly the same problem with a class that extends ContactBlock which in turn extends BlockBase. The problem occurs when placing the block in the block admin UI. I also see the failure at the call to class_exists - i.e. no return value. The parameter to class_exists looks ok. As a second test I modified a working block class that derived directly from BlockBase and instead derived it from ContactBlock. The error then occurred. It seems that deriving from a class that derives from BlockBase seems to cause the class to not autoload.

Answer (score 1):

The actual class has to be included in the `use` statement.

```
use Drupal\book\Plugin\Block\BookNavigationBlock;
```